# How to decrease Jenkins ussage of RAM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ram

I'm new to Jenkins. First shocking thing that kills me is that it's is consuming more than 2 Gigabytes of RAM while doing ..."nothing".

Is there something wrong on my setup?

I'm just interested in executing some Jenkinfile's pipelines developed by third parties. (I'm used to do CI on Unix/Shell scripts). I'm wondering whether I can launch/execute those Jenkinfile pipelines without the need of having a (2Gb of RAM) server running, maybe by just running Jenkins as an standard java application that loads my jenkinsfile, execute "anything" and ends. That is, using Jenkins as a normal script language interpreting my jenkinsfile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering myself. It looks like jenkinsfile-runner is the most suitable solution to approach this problem. It add tens of seconds to each build, but could be better if builds are not frequent saving RAM memory that can be used for "other things".

https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner

https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/02/28/serverless-jenkins/

Answer (score 1):

I found this video from Jenkins World very interesting:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTafQ-e84eY
They talk about the reason, why Jenkins uses ressoures and how you can tune the jvm.